# Lombok cannot generate setter and getter while using Ant build

Tags: java, ant, lombok

I tried to use Ant to build my Java application which contains lombok.jar.
But I always get error indicating that setter or getter is undefined for many Value Object.
I tried to de-compile to .class file generated by Ant, and these .class file didn't have setter and getter.
I made sure that Ant build can reference to the lombok.jar located in lib folder of my application project, and I tried to relocate lombok.jar to the classpath I set before, but it still doesn't work.
Also I checked the build.xml for Ant build. Nothing seems wrong in the classpath setting.

Is there anything that I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible lead : 
Make sure annotation processing is enabled:

```
<jar destfile="${annotationprocessorjar}" ... >
 ...
 <service type="javax.annotation.processing.Processor" provider="${your.annotation.processor.fully.qualified.name}"/>
```

The annotation processor will depend on the lombok version you use.

Comment: I'm using Hybris 1905. I would like where do you put this configuration?